# Leetcode 219. My python solution not working

Tags: python-3.x, sliding-window

Question is : Given an integer array nums and an integer k, return true if there are two distinct indices i and j in the array such that nums[i] == nums[j] and abs(i - j) <= k

Ex 1:
Input: nums = [1,2,3,1], k = 3
Output: true

My solution is

```
def containsNearbyDuplicate(nums ,k):
    i = 0
    for j in range(1,len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == nums[j]:
            if abs(i-j) <= k:
                return True
            return False
        i += 1
nums = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
k = 2
containsNearbyDuplicate(nums ,k)
```

What's wrong here ?
I am using Sliding-Window approach.

Comment: "Not working" is not an adequate description of what's wrong. What [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) have you tried to narrow down the cause of the problem? You need to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post. 
At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect. Please take the [tour], and read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Answer (score 0):

```
def containsNearbyDuplicate(nums ,k):
    if len(nums)==len(set(nums)):
        return False
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(nums)):
            if nums[i] == nums[j] and abs(i-j)<=k:
                return True
    return False
nums = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
k = 2
print(containsNearbyDuplicate(nums ,k)) # it will return False
```

you are using for loop so it will execute only once and after that it will
terminate